# 3-labelled automaton

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I need to draw a (kind of) automaton with every arc having:

1. a "letter label" at the midpoint of the arc,

and (some) having

2. a "number label" at the beginning of the arc,
3. a "number label" at     the end of the arc.

I thought that, instead of using plain tikz, it will be more confortable to use some existing library or package (say tikzcd, automata, tkzgraph...). But in every case I find some issues that I can not properly solve.

For example, using tikzcd I obtained the following (quite satisfactory) result

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}    

\tikzcdset{
    arrow style=tikz,               % Latin Modern, math font, tikz
    diagrams={>=stealth},            % to, stealth, latex, space
    diagrams={nodes={inner sep=1pt}},
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep = 50,row sep = 40]
    \odot \arrow[loop left,distance=3em,
     out=145,in=215,
     "y" description,
     blue]
     \arrow[r,bend left=90,red,"x" description]
    & \bullet
    \arrow[l,red, "x" description,
    "\scriptscriptstyle{(0,2)}"' very near start,
    "\scriptscriptstyle{(1,2)}"' very near end]
    \arrow[loop right,distance=3em,
     out=35,in=-35,
     "y" description,
     "\scriptscriptstyle{(0,2)}"' very near start,
    "\scriptscriptstyle{(1,2)}"' very near end,
     blue]\\
    &\bullet \arrow[lu,red,"x" description,
    "\scriptscriptstyle{(1,0)}" very near end]
    \arrow[u,blue,"y" description]
  \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image: Snapshot of the first result]

The problem is, of course, the "number labeling" of the loops. Is there a way to correctly position this labels (to appear in the start and end of the edge loop)?

I have also tried with the automata library (which I suppose is more appropriate for drawing automata, right?) with the following result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}

\tikzset{every state/.style={
    inner sep=2pt,
    minimum size=4pt,
    %fill=black
    }}

\tikzset{every edge/.append style={
    font=\tiny    %\scriptsize  \tiny
}}

\tikzset{>=stealth}  %latex, to, stealth

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state,accepting] (1) {1};
   \node[state] (4) [right=of 1] {4};
   \node[state] (3) [below=of 4] {3};
   \path[->]
        (1) edge[red,bend left,in=90,out=90]
            node {$a$}(4)
            edge[loop left,blue,min distance=10mm]
            node {$b$}(1)
        (3) edge[red]
            node {$a$}
            node[very near end] {${(1,0)}$}(1)
            edge[blue]
            node {$b$}(4)
        (4) edge[red]
            node {$a$}
            node[near end,swap] {${(1,2)}$}
            node[very near start,swap] {${(0,2)}$} (1)
            edge[loop right,blue,min distance=10mm]
            node {$b$}
            node[pos=0] {${(0,2)}$}
            node[pos=1] {${(1,2)}$}(4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Snapshot of the result]

Here, the problems are more. At least:

1. positioning of "number labels" in loops (as before),
2. simulating the "description" effect to position "letter labels" like in the tikcd example,
3. bad spacing in "number labels" (probably caused by the \tiny font size).

Do you know how to fix these problems?
Which option do you think is better for drawing this kind of automata?

Of course, I am not an expert. Sorry if I am asking something trivial o easy to find.

Comment: Did you check this: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/automata-and-petri-nets/ ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you mind adding your preamble as well? I mean the document class and the packages.

Comment: Ok, I will add the preamble as soon as i can reach my computer (several hours). Thanks.

Comment: @suitangi No problem. It's just to see what packages are you using. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `auto` you can fix where you want your labels. By default `auto` place labels `above` or `below` the path. Without `auto` they are placed `on` the path and if you want they cut the path, use `fill=white`.

Just an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}

\tikzset{every state/.style={
    inner sep=2pt,
    minimum size=4pt,
    %fill=black
    }}

\tikzset{every edge/.append style={
    font=\tiny
}}

\tikzset{>=stealth}  %latex, to, stealth

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2cm, on grid]
   \node[state,accepting] (1) {1};
   \node[state] (4) [right=of 1] {4};
   \node[state] (3) [below=of 4] {3};
   \path[->]
        (1) edge[red,bend left,in=90,out=90]
            node[fill=white] {$a$}(4)
            edge[loop left,blue,min distance=10mm]
            node[fill=white] {$b$}(1)
        (3) edge[red]
            node[fill=white] {$a$}
            node[near end, below left=-1mm] {(1,0)}(1)
            edge[blue]
            node[fill=white] {$b$}(4)
        (4) edge[red]
            node[fill=white] {$a$}
            node[pos=.8,above=-1mm] {(1,2)}
            node[pos=.2,above=-1mm] {(0,2)} (1)
            edge[loop right,blue,min distance=10mm]
            node[fill=white] {$b$}
            node[pos=0.1, above] {(0,2)}
            node[pos=0.9, below] {(1,2)}(4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank  you!, this fairly solves the positioning of "number labels" in loops. However I still have some doubts:
(1) can I reduce the white space around "letter labels"?
(2) now the spacing in "number labels" is correct, why is that?
(3) why are you including tkz-graph and tkz-berge packages? what is its use?

Comment: @suitangi (1): Space around letter inside nodes is adjusted with `inner sep` (initially `.3333em`). `node[fill=white, inner sep=0pt]` will suppress it. (2): Because they don't use `math` format. Try `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} (1,2) $(1,2)$ $(1,\!2)$ (a,b) $(a,b)$ $(a,\!b)$ \end{document}` a look at differences between them. (3): Because they where there and I forgot to delete them. Now I did it.

Comment: great!. Thank you again, and oops...  sorry about (3). :)